# How to retrieve the full paths of javascript event.DataTransfer object passed into c++ npapi plugin's function?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I have a function exposed to javascript:

```
bool handleDrop( const NPVariant * args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant* result){
     //Extract the full paths from the DataTransfer object passed into args
}
```

which gets called from Javascript from an onDrop(event) handler:

```
plugin.handleDrop(event.DataTransfer);
```

I've had success with the ActiveX version with:

```
void handleDrop (IDispatch* arg){
     //Extract paths using QueryInterface for IID_IHTMLDataTransfer,
     // IID_IServiceProvider, IID_IDataObject  which gets dropfiles list
}
```

I want to do the same thing for the NPAPI version.
According to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer
The datatransfer object looks like it implements the nsIDOMDataTransfer interface.

Is this even possible to extract the full dropped files path from the datatransfer object with NPAPI, and how do you actually do the conversions to get there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *minor* issue you run into here is that nsIDOMDataTransfer is not actually NPAPI. That's XPCOM, which is a different (but in some historical cases related) thing. If you look at the docs for [NPN_GetValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_GetValue) you'll find that NPNVDomWindow, which once could give you a XPCOM reference to the DOM window, is [no longer supported as of FireFox 3.6](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/01/firefox-3-6-has-removed-support-for-xpcom-plugins/). Similarly, you can't pass in objects from javascript and get XPCOM references to them as of the same time period.

Part of the reason for this is that XPCOM as a method of implementing a scripting interface on a plugin has been deprecated for years and people were still trying to use it. No other NPAPI browser supports it, they all use NPRuntime.

Anyway, the long and short of things is that if you can't get the information you need with javascript you won't be able to with the plugin either.  The good news is that a plugin can be a drag and drop target. The bad news is I've never needed to so I don't know how =] That might be a reasonable choice for another question.

Sorry I can't be much help

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I had a requirement to make a windowless plugin that could get full paths from files dropped onto specific elements.  I guess a windowed plugin that accepts drag and drop is the only way to go to get full path data.

Comment: that seems likely. you might look at the source code to google gears, which supported drag and drop.